# Where did the question with fun captcha combinations go?

Tags: discussion, captcha

I could have SWORN there was a question on SO or here that had interesting word combinations that pop up in the Captcha.  Am I crazy, or where is it?
[image: hurr]

Comment: You are crazy, if you want to add a new one.

Comment: I'm virtually certain it was in the blog, but I can't find it now. Maybe I'm crazy too.

Comment: I've seen it mentioned in the comments of blog posts.

Comment: You broke that captcha. It actually says "Wishful beginning"!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, here it is: [Are you a human being?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/06/are-you-a-human-being/).

I *thought* it was in the blog somewhere.

It would be more fun if we could vote, but I don't think it really belongs on Meta.